# how to make a host in the Lan to forward traffic between other hosts in the same LAN in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu-14.04, local-area-network, forwarding

I am setting a test topology as the following:

```
Switch1-----Switch2-----Switch3
   |           |           |
   H1          H2          H3
```

I want the traffic going from H1 to H3 to go visit H2 before being forwarded to H3. I have set flow rules on my switches (OpenVSwitch) to do that. However, when traffic goes to H2, it got dropped there.

I wonder what configurations I should add to H2 (Ubuntu 14.04) in order to enable H2 to forward a traffic that is not destined to it, nor originated from it.

Comment: Show your topology in line as test, it is very simple and does not need a picture.

Comment: I tried it , but it wasn't formatted right ,

Comment: s1 -- s2 -- s3
 I       I      I
h1     h2    h3

Comment: I edited it for you, the change should appear after peer review. Basically indent by 4 spaces to inter preformatted mode. See https://serverfault.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for you answers, I finally could do it by rewriting the destination Mac address of the packets in the switch. the problem was that , the host 2 drops packets that are not destined to it ( different Mac destination address). thus by rewriting the destination Mac address to host2's Mac address in switch 2, and by activating the IP forwarding in host 2, traffic is successfully redirected. 
so the step one , is to tell S2 to send traffic to Host 2 with destination Mac of host 2.
and step 2, is to tell S2 to rewrite the the Mac address of traffic returning from host 2 to host 3 Mac address ( to restore the original mac address).

Answer (score 1):

You must allow forwarding

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

If you want have this permanent then edit the file /etc/sysctl.conf

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Comment: I already enabled forwarding but no way , I get the packets coming throught h2-eth0 , but no outcoming.

Comment: Do you have firewall active on H2? What Is are on hosts?

Comment: I haven't set firewall rules, but iptables shows that the chains INPUT,Forward and OUTPUT are set to ACCEPT by default

Comment: I guess that H1 and H3 have both a single NIC while H2 is multihomed, right? What is the Ip config for each host?

Comment: all H1,H2 and H3 have only one interface , they all belong to the same LAN 10.0.0.0/8